# How to restore binary file of Debian Jessie target in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: linux, shell, debian, wkhtmltopdf

For Wkhtmltopdf installation, I followed this [documentation](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

For Debian Jessie, `sudo scripts/build.py setup-schroot-jessie` created `/var/chroot/jessie-amd64`. But I deleted this repertory by mistake `(with rm -R)`

When I raise `sudo scripts/build.py setup-schroot-jessie` he said that the directory `/var/chroot/jessie-amd64` already exists.

Can you help me ? I am really newbie in linux commands ...